# What exactly is a PWSTR and why use this naming compared to char*, std::string, or CString in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, string

In various c++ code you often see different usage of strings: PWSTR, char*, std::string, CString, etc ...

When is the best time to use PWSTR as compared to any other string type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a PWSTR would be a `wchar_t` string pointer.  That is a UNICODE (usually UCS2) string with each character taking 16 bits.

a `char*` would be a pointer 8 bits per character. this could be ASCII, ANSI, UTF8, or one of many hundreds of other encodings. Although you only need to worry about encodings if you need the string to hold languages other than English or special symbols.

In general, The Windows API is all UNICODE internally so most Windows programmers use wchar strings.  But `std::string` and `CString` can both be UNICODE if the right symbols are `#defined`, so your choice between `PWSTR`, `std::string` and `CString` will be a matter of preference or the convention of the codebase you work with.

Comment: On Windows, wchar_t is always UTF-16.

Comment: What needs to be defined to change `std::string` into a container of `wchar_t`?  Is that even legal with respect to the Standard - I believe that `std::string` is required to be `std::basic_string<char,...>`.

Comment: @D.Shawley: it would be std:wstring if you want to be pedantic about it.

Comment: @Nemanja: PWSTR is a #define, it's not restricted to windows, it's used by anyone who believes in encoding type information into type names.

Comment: @John: PWSTR is strictly speaking a typedef and a part of Windows SDK. Haven't seen it anywhere else.

Comment: @Nemanja. Wrong. On windows wchar_t is always 16 bits. This doesn't guarantee UTF16. You can quite happily use a wchar_t* to hold utf32 where 2 wchar_t's are each symbol. Perhaps you meant that in the windows api wchar_t is always utf16?

Comment: @kts: That's exactly what I mean - as far as Windows API is concerned, wchar_t* is UTF-16 only. For your own purposes, of course you can put anything you want into wchar_t.

Comment: error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t *' to 'const PWSTR'

Answer (score 4):

When whichever library you are working with wants a `PWSTR`. This is a, according to naming convention used in Windows, pointer to a string of wide-characters.

By default, you should use `std::string`/`std::wstring`. Only when you interface with someone expecting something else should you change that.

You can get a `PCWSTR` from a `std::wstring` with the `c_str()` method. `CString` is MFC, if I recall.

Comment: @nobugz: I said `const` for a reason :P

Comment: "wants a PWSTR" ... " get a PCWSTR from ", PWSTR != PCWSTR.

Answer (score 2):

PWSTR= pointer to a wide string = WCHAR* in windows

The Windows SDK is very hung up on typedefs for types and pointers to types.

"When in Rome" - use whatever string type the project you're working on requires. String types aren't important enough to stress out about or try to force your one true way upon whatever is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Its from the Windows API.

I remember it like this.

Its a *P*-ointer to a *W*-ide string.

It would be used in a Unicode application. Its use would be when you are making calls to Windows. The best type would be actually `LPTSTR` *P*-ointer to a *T*-yped string (either Unicode or ANSI.

Comment: `LPTSTR` (as all these _T_ strings is only needed when you want your code to compile with both Unicode _and_ ANSI settings. IME that's rarely needed. (Once you've gone Unicode, why would you need ANSI?)

Answer (score 1):

The best time to use PWSTR is if all the code you are editing/extending is already using it. It is usually best to keep coding in the paradigm of whatever code you're working on.

Similarly, if you're making heavy use of a particular library that declares its strings in a certain way, it's usually best to keep that type of string in your own code. So working with Windows MFC, you'd use CString. Old-style Win32 would usually be LPCTSTR and similar.

It's often a matter of style rather than a particular implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

`PWSTR` is an identifier from somewhere in `<windows.h>`. It's best used when dealing with Windows API function that require such a thing, and best avoided otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the file WinNT.h in the Windows SDK - you'll see that PWSTR is a typedef for WCHAR*. It is not a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Coming into this very late; there's a somewhat better reason to use `PWSTR` and related types than there was a decade ago: Microsoft's [Source-code Annotation Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-sal-annotations-to-reduce-c-cpp-code-defects?view=vs-2019). These are markers used in the code to give the compiler lint-like hints as to the intention of the code, which is like GNU `__attribute__` or C++ `[[attribute]]` on mega steroids.

With SAL, you can annotate your code and data with tokens that indicate higher level intentions: this is an input parameter, that's output, this can't be null, you must check the return value of this function, etc.

It's a very, very long list, expanding on the older and much simpler `IN`, `OUT`, and `INOUT` parameter markers.

In the old days, the Windows header files included:

```
typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
typedef WCHAR *PWCHAR;  // implies pointing to just one wchar

typedef WCHAR *PWSTR;   // implies pointing to a string
```

Conceptually I understand what they were trying to accomplish, showing intent of how it's to be used, but was so verbose I never used them.

But now, it's:

```
typedef wchar_t WCHAR;   // same as before
typedef WCHAR *PWCHAR;   // same as before

typedef _Null_terminated WCHAR *PWSTR; // NEW
```

Here, the `_Null_terminated` attribute is carried along with the type and is used by their code analysis infrastructure to suss out errors. Using distinct types - pointing to just one character versus pointing to a string - really does help it drill down to intentional behavior.

The headers are full of these annotations: an example from `<stdio.h>`:

```
_Check_return_
extern int __cdecl rename(
   _In_z_ char const *_OldFilename,
   _In_z_ char const *_NewFilename);
```

Both of the parameters, though technically pointing to a single character, tell the compiler that we're in string territory after all.

I'm still not using the `PWSTR`-flavored types, but if you use them, you get some source checking for free.  SAL has found quite a few bugs in my code just this morning.