# Conversion of wstring* to PWSTR

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to convert wstring* to PWSTR*.
As per http://devsolvd.com/questions/how-to-convert-std-string-to-lpcstr PWSTR is wchar_t*. So PWSTR* is wchar_t**

As per document http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string, wstring is wchar_t. So wstring* is whar_t*

to convert wstring to PWSTR, i am trying following expression:

```
std::wstring *currentMetric =...
PWSTR *metric=...
*metric=currentMetric
```

It is getting error "cannot convert from 'std::wstring *' to 'PWSTR'"
I don't want to use c_str as it return PCWSTR and const_cast can give PWSTR but reassignment of the variable might lead to data corruption.

I want to know any other method to do so.

Thanks

Edit:  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096762/what-exactly-is-a-pwstr-and-why-use-this-naming-compared-to-char-stdstring) suggests to use c_str(), but I wanted to use something other than c_str()

Comment: You can use the `c_str()` method to access the raw data.

Comment: The much maligned system-hungarian to the rescue.  wstring::c_str() returns a *const wchar_t*.  PCWSTR is *pointer to constant wide string*.  There is no C in PWSTR.

Comment: did you include WinNT.h?

Comment: The question here is slightly different. I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this:
    *metric = &(*currentMetric)[0];

PS.I didn't want to use c_str as it returns PCWSTR which can be cons_cast to PWSTR. But reassignment of hthe variable might lead to data corruption

Comment: You should double check how this pointer is going to be used, if you pass it to a C function that alters its content you may have to resync its length (if the C function truncates it) or to make sure it's big enough to begin with (if it's an output buffer).

Comment: Thanks Matteo, i will check that once.

Comment: This was actually quite helpful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This part is not correct:

> As per document http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string, wstring is wchar_t. So wstring* is whar_t*

wstring is a wrapper around wchar_t*, not wchar_t. To access the underlying wchar_t*, use the [c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member function.

Comment: c_str returns PCWSTR. This is a constant variable type which i don't want. That's why i wanted to avoid using c_str.